# How can I design an object to represent all HTML form elements?

Tags: c#, .net, html, webforms

**Disclaimer:** This is a personal project that I'm doing for fun. I'm not looking to use existing libraries since it would take some of the joy out of [learning more about wheels](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-unless-you-plan-on-learning-more-about-wheels.html).

That being said, I'm working on a web spider and I've come to the problem of how to represent HTML form elements with a single object.

What I want to do is have an "HTML Document" object, which contains an array of all form elements as one of its properties. The problem is that I can't figure out a way to represent `<input />` tags, as well as `<select />` tags, since select tags can have multiple child `<option />` tags.

Is there any good way to represent both `<input />` tags, which store basically only name/value pairs, and `<select />` tags which have an array of name/value pairs in the same class?

The best idea I've come up with so far is to treat the `<option />` tags of a `<select />` tag as individual form fields, similar to how I would represent `<input type="radio" />` or `<input type="checkbox" />`.

So I would have this:

```
class FormField {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

And then a collection class for iterating would:

- The collection class would be an "array of arrays". The outer array would have a single inner array for each name in the HTML document.
- Its indexer could get fields by Name. This index would return an array of `FormField` objects.
- When enumerating over the entire document's form fields, each iteration would have an array of `FormField` objects, since it would be an array of arrays.

Is this the best solution, or is there a simpler way to represent this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to represent the dom structure, or the values as they would appear in a http-post?

Two inputs with the same name will cause the value to be posted twice, and read similar to as if you had checked checkboxes (with same name). And have you checked what happens if you have both a textbox and a checkbox with the same name? Can you differ between them in the resulting http-post? And what type should you be using in that case?

Tried a simple NameValueCollection which would allow you to store several string values per key?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to perform an HTTP POST. I'm not looking to represent a DOM structure because the main purpose of what I'm building is to be a spider. I've written a very basic HTML parser to parse out individual nodes. I'm at the point now where I just want to decide how to represent the nodes needed to attempt to crawl a page. That's why I don't want to build a full page DOM, since building a DOM object wouldn't necessarily help me get things like hyperlinks & form elements.

Comment: Web spiders usually don't follow forms/http-posts, or attempt to fake these.

Answer (score 1):

I would view the entire document as a structure of parent-child links starting with the body tag.  The first tag is the body tag.  Any top level div, p, form, etc tags would go into the Children object.  When you get to form elements like select, you can then fill in the values of the select as more htmlObjects

```
class htmlObject {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<htmlObject> Children { get; }
}
```

From your example, what you are missing is the Children property to represent the underlying properties.

When you are ready to define the elements in greater detail, then class htmlObject becomes interface IhtmlObject and you then create specialized classes for each tag.  Then the specialize tag can implement the functionality you want to handle each tags special conditions.

Comment: I considered that, but I'm trying to avoid needing to build an entire DOM tree and only create a list of elements that would be important to my spider (links & form fields, possibly image elements and external CSS/JavaScript URLs)

Comment: That fine... then build the structure with the form tag as the base element instead of the body tag.  Everything else applies from that point on.